# How can I include an ALTER VIEW statement in a transaction for a deploy script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running SQL Server 2005 on prod, but developing on 2008, and I need to alter a view to add a column.  However I'm having trouble creating the deploy script because I need to wrap it in a transaction like this

```
begin tran;

alter view [dbo].[v_ViewName] with schemabinding
as 
    select ... 

    /* do other stuff */
commit;
```

When I do this the SQL IDE underlines the alter statement with an error saying that the 'ALTER VIEW' statement must be the only statement in a batch. ANd if I ignore this and just try and run it anyway it gives this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: You can set the 2008's compatibility level so it runs as 2005, if you haven't already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A transaction can span multiple batches:

```
begin tran;
GO

alter view [dbo].[v_ViewName] 
with schemabinding
as         
  select ...     
GO

/* do other stuff */
GO

commit;
GO
```